# How to prevent Oracle from using a cached query plan?

Tags: oracle, query-performance

I'm using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production on linux.  I have a simple query that joins 4 tables.  Typically, it is first run after a few rows of test data are inserted into the tables and it runs in < .1 second.  If I then insert 50,000 rows into 2 of the tables, the query takes > 10 minutes to run.  If I change the query in any way at all it will run in a few tenths of a second.

It appears that the query execution plan is cached and the optimizer is using the one it generated when there were just a few rows in each of the 4 tables.  I tried updating the statistics for the schema (using gather schema statistics in sql developer) and it does not speed up the slow version of the query.  The only solution I found was to run

```
    ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH shared_pool;
```

Then the next time the slow query is run, it executes in < 1 second.

Flushing the shared_pool every time you insert some data is clearly not a good idea.  What is the correct way to deal with this situation?  Would the adaptive query optimization in Oracle 12 address this sort of problem?

Here's the query.  When it is running slow, even just changing the alias from abc to abcd (or anything else) is sufficient to make it run about 1000x faster.

```
SELECT
  COUNT (*) cnt_
FROM 
(
    SELECT
     tg.name group_name ,
     tot.obj_type object_type ,
     tgol.test_access access_type,
     count (*) test_object_count
    FROM test_group tg
    , test_group_object_link tgol
    , test_object tobj
    , test_object_type tot
    WHERE tgol.test_group_id=tg.id
    AND tgol.test_object_id=tobj.id
    AND tobj.test_object_type_id=tot.id
    AND tg.isvalid='Y'
    AND tgol.isvalid='Y'
    AND tobj.isvalid='Y'
    AND tot.isvalid='Y'
    GROUP BY tg.name , tot.obj_type , tgol.test_access
    ORDER BY tg.name , tot.obj_type , tgol.test_access
)
abc
```

Comment: gathering the statistics after a significant data has been inserted is the good solution here, it should normally solve your problem. If not, gather the explain plan to verify why it doesn't work. You can also invalidate the plan in cache when gathering statistics by using:
    BEGIN
        dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(owname=>'USER',no_invalidate=>false);
    END;

Comment: Gathering stats may or may not invalidate the execution plan for the query (meaning, cause it to be parsed again the next time it is run). user35... is correct: if you set `no_invalidate` to `false` when you call `gather_schema_stats`, that will do it. Normally you shouldn't have to do that though; the default is for Oracle to decide if new stats should invalidate the plan. Perhaps this default has been changed in your DB or schema. See references when you read about `no_invalidate` in the Oracle documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question and the info about no_invalidate.  The setting for no_invalidate is auto_invalidate.  But even the next day, the same bad plan is being used.